# Plot graph from the bunch of selected excel sheet

Tags: python

There are lot of csv excel sheets in a folder. All excel sheet contains data only in first 3 columns. I will select corresponding csv sheet from a lot of csv sheets and then plot it.Here is the code

```
import os
path = "F:\\Users\\Desktop\\Data\\Summary"
files = []
test_folders = os.listdir(path) 
folder_data = os.listdir(path)
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.csv' in file:
            files.append(file)
for i, f in enumerate(files):
    print("%d-%s"%( i,f))
    csv_code = int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: "))
    csv_path = folder_data + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code] 

    df = pd.read_csv(csv_path, header=None)
    df1 = df.iloc[:,0:2]
    plt.plot(df1[0], df1[1])
```

When i run the code i want the Output to be displayed as follows (i mean i want all csv files from the folder to be displayed so that i can select what i want):

```
0-Test_Summary_1.csv
1-Test_Summary_2.csv
2-Test_Summary_3.csv
3-Test_Summary_4.csv
4-Test_Summary_5.csv
5-Test_Summary_6.csv etc
```

so that i select the corresponding code like 1 or 2 or 3 to plot.

Here is the error

```
   csv_path = folder_data + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code]

TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

Answer (score 0):

`folder_data` is not a defined variable in the code you have provided? By extensions `folder_data[csv_code]` isn't either.
Is the line you're receiveing an error on supposed to be:

`csv_path = path + "\\" + csv_code`

Comment: inspite of defining  `folder_data` it was showing that error

Comment: ```csv_path = path + "\\" + csv_code 

                                                               TypeError: must be str, not int```

Comment: `csv_code = int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: "))`  I believe is causing your error. You can't concatenate strings and integers. So :


`csv_code = str(int(input("Enter corresponding code to plot: ")))`

Comment: Sir,I am getting  this error-    ```csv_path = path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str``` Kindly reply

Comment: The error is correct. 
Even if we assume `folder_data` is a list (it isn't as you haven't defined it), `folder_data[csv_code]` makes no sense. You are trying to get the [csv_code] item from the list. Python expects this to be number: i.e 1st item 2nd item. Read up on python list indexing.
As I said before your coed needs to be this: `csv_path = path + "\\" + csv_code`

Comment: defined ```folder_data[csv_code]```. and used ```csv_path = path + "\\" + csv_code``` in the code but still getting error as ``` csv_path = path + "\\" + csv_code

TypeError: must be str, not int```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your actual error message:
`folder_data` is a list, to which you want to add a string `"\\"`, which does not work. In case you want to append `"\\"` to each element in the list, you would have to do the following: `folder_data = [i+"\\" for i in folder_data]`. What you might be wanting to do is use `path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code}` instead to get the full path to a single csv file.

Comment: In your line `csv_path = folder_data + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code] ` folder_data is a list, therefore running pd.read_csv() on the result will not work. I am not 100% sure what you are trying to do but what you might be wanting to do is use `path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code}` instead.

Comment: ``` csv_path = path + "\\" + folder_data[csv_code]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str ``` error

Comment: This error means that `csv_code` is a string. In your code you are correctly casting it to an int, so unfortunately I can't say why that is.